# How can I compare the date from text file to today's date

Tags: php, date, comparison

```
<?php
$myFile = strtolower('date.txt');
$lines = file($myFile);     
$expire_date = $lines[0];



$date = strtotime($expire_date);
//$date->format("y,m,d");
$now = new DateTime();
$now->format("y,m,d");

if($now < $date) {
    echo 'Have not reached date yet.';
}else{
echo 'Date in file is old';
}
?>
```

Content of my date.txt file -

2018,2,18 (this is line 1)

Test (This is line 2 in my file)

I want to compare 2018,2,18, line 1 in the file, with the current date. Code keeps saying that the date is old when it's clearly in the future. Is it because line 1, although will return the date, is actually an array or not a date?

Comment: Have you checked what `$date` looks like?

Comment: I echo out $date and it seems to be blank. I thought strtotime was supposed to convert my string to time? Unless my $expire_date isn't considered a string?

Comment: Or it's not a string that the function can make sense of... ;) `$date` will actually be a boolean `false`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strtotime($expire_date)` is returning `FALSE`. I have replaced comma with dash in your date string. Also consider I'm using `time()` function which returns current Unix timestamp. I have considered the date in your file is UTC date.

```
$myFile = strtolower('date.txt');
$lines = file($myFile);     
$date = $lines[0];
$date = str_replace(',', '-', $date);
$date = strtotime($date);

if(time() < $date) {
    echo 'Have not reached date yet.';
}else{
    echo 'Date in file is old';
}
```

Or you can also create your date from the format in file:

```
$myFile = strtolower('date.txt');
$lines = file($myFile);     
$date = $lines[0];
$date = date_create_from_format('Y,m,d', $date);
$date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
$date = strtotime($date);

if(time() < $date) {
    echo 'Have not reached date yet.';
}else{
    echo 'Date in file is old';
}
```

Comment: When I tried out this code, it's telling me that the date is old. However, the date in my file is 2018,02,20. Which is in the future

Comment: I don't see your code anymore? I could always change my answer of course, and I appreciate any help.